# R proper usage of `rank` while filtering with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

The following code ranks the iris data frame by sepal length.

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% filter(rank(Sepal.Length) <= 5)  # bottom 5 values
iris %>% filter(rank(Sepal.Length) > 5)  # everything but bottom 5
```

How do I get the top 5 values using the `rank` function? I can tell you it's not this:

```
iris %>% filter(rank(Sepal.Length) <= -5)
```

Comment: You have to check again what your code does. `iris %>% filter(rank(Sepal.Length) <= 3)` will not return 3 rows. Have a look at what `rank` does.

Comment: Would it be better to stick with `top_n()`?

Comment: Yes! Definitely `top_n(5,Sepal.Length)` or `top_n(-5,Sepal.Length)`. Or you can use `arrange() %>% slice()`. Up to you. The relationship between `rank` and the actual values is a bit tricky to be used to select a specific number of rows. If you run `iris %>% mutate(r = rank(Sepal.Length)) %>% arrange(r)` you will see yourself.

Comment: Yes, `top_n` filters for the n highest or lowest values. `rank` assigns a rank where 1 is the lowest value and the highest value has the same number as the total number of rows. A rank of -5 won't make sense since they're all positive numbers

Comment: @camille that's right. So, the reason why the `iris %>% filter(rank(Sepal.Length) <= 3)` won't work is because there are ties and more than 3 rows will be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be this `iris %>% filter(rank(desc(Sepal.Length)) <= 5)`